# NVM ls command not picking existing Node version

Tags: node.js, macos, apple-m1, nvm

I have already installed Node specific version in my system.

Now i have installed NVM using below command.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

if I run nvm in terminal , its showing all NVM options user can try. ( NVM installation is Successful)

My doubt is it not taking up already installed node version on nvm ls

PFA

**nvm ls**

```
    > ->       system
iojs -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
```

Please let me know how NVM can detect already installed node version.
If i install other node version with NVM , i may loose track of already installed node version as its not coming up in nvm ls

Answer (score 0):

When I installed nvm recently I had to also do this step: `nvm install node` to install the latest version. Then you can check the following: `node -v`

If you do `nvm ls remote` it will display all available versions, then you can install any of them and view which ones you picked using `nvm ls`.

I set my node version default like this: `nvm alias default <version>`

I just ran into this issue as well using nvm. I did have to delete the package-lock.json file in the project directory and rebuild. But after doing so it seems to not have any trouble going between the node versions.

I just noticed you asked the question 4 months ago! I hope you were able to resolve the issue!